# GMW Multiplication AND for 2 parties

Tags: secret-sharing, multiparty-computation, xor, oblivious-transfer

I am looking into the [GMW](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/gradcrypto2/f13/lecture13.pdf) protocol's evaluation for multiplication in 2 parties. I have referred to different materials on it but I didn't exactly understand how $a_i b_j + a_j b_i$ is calculated in a 2 party setting.

As you know multiplication in GMW is given as $$(a_1\oplus a_2\oplus \cdots \oplus a_n)(b_1\oplus b_2\oplus \cdots\oplus b_n) = \bigoplus_i(a_i b_i) \bigoplus_{i<j}(a_i b_j \oplus a_j b_i).$$

Finding the first term in this equation is easy where we just multiply $a_i$ and $b_i$ share. I have trouble understanding the second term which involves Oblivious Transfer.

Comment: Hi, @kelalaka you are right. It should be the `\bigoplus`

Comment: This is the equation, https://imgur.com/a/NhFNaSb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more accessible explanation can be found in [these](https://www.csa.iisc.ac.in/~arpita/SecureComputation15/Lecture9_10.pdf) lecture notes.

The idea is to "simulate" multiplication using OT. The OT is run twice, in the first run with Party $0$ as the sender and Party $1$ as the receiver, and in the second run with the roles reversed. The first run proceeds as follows:

1. Party $0$ selects a random bit $r_0$ and $r_0\oplus a_0$ as the input to the OT
2. Party $1$ sets $b_1$ as the selection bit. 
   It is not hard to see that Party $1$ effectively computes $r_0\oplus a_0\cdot b_1$: if $b_1=0$, it obtains $r_0$ and otherwise it obtains $r_1\oplus a_0$.

Similarly, in the second run, Party $0$ computes $r_1\oplus a_1\cdot b_0$.

Now, Party $0$'s share is $$a_0b_0\oplus r_0\oplus (r_1\oplus a_1\cdot b_0)$$ whereas Party $1$'s share is $$a_1b_1\oplus r_1\oplus (r_0\oplus a_0\cdot b_1).$$
It is not hard to see that when XORed, they yield $(a_0\oplus a_1)\cdot(b_0\oplus b_1)=a\cdot b$.

An alternative method to do multiplication is to use Beaver's trick [B]. An explanation can be found [here](https://cs.au.dk/~orlandi/ecrypt/ECRYPTPart1.pdf).

[B] Beaver, [Efficient multiparty protocols using circuit randomization](https://cs.au.dk/~orlandi/ecrypt/ECRYPTPart1.pdf), Crypto 91

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Occams_Trimmer. This made so much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are party $I$, and your friend is party $J$, secret values are $a$ and $b$. The result of the multiplication would look like:

$$
a.b = (a_i \oplus a_j) . (b_i\oplus b_j) = (a_ib_i) \oplus (a_ib_j) \oplus (a_jb_i) \oplus (a_jb_j)
$$
$I$ and $J$ already have these shares and need no communication for $a_ib_i$ or $a_jb_j$. But for $(a_ib_j)$ and $(a_jb_i)$, they do need other's input. $I$ selects a random value r and creates a table with four entries depending on the values of $I$'s and possible values of $J$ with entries $e$ like $r \oplus a_ib_j \oplus a_jb_i$.

$$
\begin{align}
a_j = 0,b_j &= 0: e = r \\
a_j = 0,b_j &= 1: e = r \oplus a_i \\
a_j = 1,b_j &= 0: e = r \oplus b_i \\
a_j = 1,b_j &= 1: e = r \oplus a_i \oplus b_i \\
\end{align}
$$

Although these entries look confusing, note that $J$ already knows $a_j$ and $b_j$ values. And any if these entries are $0$, then look at the equation $r \oplus a_ib_j \oplus a_jb_i$. This would have one or two entries evaluate to $0$. That is why the table was constructed that way. Clearly, if $I$ and $J$ engages in a 1-out-of-4 Oblivious Transfer protocol now, then $J$ can only retrieve one entry from the table. So $I$ would be having the random number $r$ and $J$ would be having the computed value xor'ed with $r$. Meaning they share the multiplication result but not the result itself.

Comment: Hi @Hasan Iqbal, thank you for the explanation. I have another follow-up question. How does party B know what value to "choose" from Party A in the 1-out-of-4 OT protocol?

Comment: Hi @rakshitnaidu , A would encrypt all four of these entries. However, B knows only a_j and b_j. So he would only be able to decrypt one entry of the table.

Comment: What algorithms can be used to encrypt A's entries?

Comment: There are many public key encryption schemes that can be used. RSA for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hasan Iqbal !